# How do I get a Judy Array example to compile correctly?

Tags: arrays, gcc, compiler-construction

I am attempting to compile the example given at http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/JudySL_3x.htm#JSLG. I have downloaded, `configure`'d, `make`'d, and `sudo make install`'d the Judy library as per the distribution. However, when I compile (GCC on a Mac), I receive the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_JudySLFreeArray", referenced from:
    _main in ccziTK43.o
"_JudySLNext", referenced from:
    _main in ccziTK43.o
"_JudySLIns", referenced from:
    _main in ccziTK43.o
"_JudySLFirst", referenced from:
    _main in ccziTK43.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can Anyone point Me in the direction of information on how to resolve this? (Just for the record, the file being compiled is a C module, yes.)

Also, My command is simply `gcc test.c`.

Comment: Looks like you're not linking against the judy library.  Show your compile command.

Comment: I added the command to the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `gcc` to link against the Judy library, using the `-l` option -- e.g.

```
gcc -lJudy test.c
```